# What percentage of my binary is taken up by a class/function template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I am a game developer, and I often find myself writing specialized, templated containers for my needs.

After watching one of my (now) favorite cppcon talks, I am interested in finding the percentage of my final binary that is taken up by a given class/function template in order to determine if some hoisting would be beneficial.

[Here](https://youtu.be/qYN6eduU06s?t=16m30s) , Nicolas mentions that programmers at Ubisoft used their in-house .obj analyzer to determine that their `Array` class was taking ~80% of their total binary size before they got it down to ~15% (in debug targets) by hoisting.

I want to know how to write such a tool. Specifically, am looking for a tool that can tell me:

1. the percentage of total binary size taken by all member and non-member functions of a class given its unmangled name and
2. the percentage of total binary size taken by an individual function(member or non-member) given its unmangled name.

I want to know how to do this in both windows and linux environments for code compiled with the gcc, clang, and Microsoft compilers.

For example, I would like something along the lines of:

```
./<toolname> <compiler sepecific options and/or whatever> <class/function name> \
<list of object files>
```

If the size of a function was asked for:

```
Summary for function <name>:
Total Size: <size in bytes> (<percentage>)
```

If the size of a class was asked for:

```
Summary for class <name>:
Total Size: <size in bytes> (<percentage>)
    member function <name>: <size> (<percentage>)
    ...
    non-member function <name>: <size> (<percentage>)
    ...
```

I am confident that I could do this myself with a slightly non-trivial program, but I thought it would be a good idea to ask here first in case there is some combination of built-in or freely available CLI tools that can be used to get this kind of information.

If your solution contains a combination of well documented tools, I don't need an explanation. However, if you write a custom tool, I would like a broad overview of your approach.

Comment: You don't need to write such a tool. A linker map file will give you all this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the program with debug information, so the symbol table with each symbol position will be present in the executable headers. Use readelf or objdump, for example, to get this information.